# Return Environment variable from a Java function and set the same in Jenkins for running builds

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, automation, testng

I have a Java function written in my project that allows me to set value of the environment i want to use for running my automation tests.

```
public static String setURL(String paramSet) {

        if (paramSet.equalsIgnoreCase("env1")) {
            baseURL = env1;

        } else if (paramSet.equalsIgnoreCase("env2")) {
            baseURL = env2;
        }
        return baseURL;
    }

    public static String getURL() {
        return setURL("env1");
    }
```

The above written code returns me the URL and then it is used in all the tests as it is. How do i start and telling to my Java project through Jenkins on which environment i want to trigger the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi why would You like to pass environemnt variable from Java to Jenkins? Usually its done in the opposite way. On Jenkins You can define parameters eg. `BASE_URL` and pass them to the command that You're using for building Your project. For maven it would looks like that:

```
maven clean install -DBASE_URL="$MY_JENKINS_PARAM"
```

Then You would be able to get their values in Java

```
public static String getUrl() {
    return System.getenv("BASE_URL"));
}
```

Comment: i am running the jenkins build via fetching code through github. how would that work? can you help me out. that is why i thought of passing the one stored in java program to jenkins because code will be running on jenkins actually.

Comment: What command are You executing in order to run tests/ build project on Jenkins?

Comment: maven clean install

Comment: Cool, now please show me one of the examples of using `getURL()` method in Your test? Another thing, Your code is a bit strange, usually setter sets value and getter returns value. Going back to my previous post, how about doing sth like this:
`public static String getURL() {  return System.getenv("MY_URL_PROPERTY")}`
and executing `maven clean install -DMY_URL_PROPERTY="env1"` ?

Comment: got it, second one works! but would i now need to create 2 different job in jenkins for production and staging having set 2 different maven goals like maven clean install ```-DMY_URL_PROPERTY="env1"``` and ```maven clean install -DMY_URL_PROPERTY="env2"```

Comment: basically i wanted to know whats the usual practice here else there would be multiple jobs for staging and production

Comment: No, You should just add parameter to Jenkins job and pass it to maven command :) This way You can choose between building Your app for dev/staging/prod etc. So at the end You would end up with something like this `maven clean install -DMY_URL_PROPERTY="$MY_JENKINS_PARAM"` This link might also help You this pattern: http://bayley.green-gaillard.com/blog/?p=92

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194990/discussion-between-icantcode-and-www).